# BS4 | Python | Scraping specific data in div with multiple values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to Python, but I've started experimenting with web scraping with BS4
with some success, but I'm now on a new personal project where I'm indexing AutoTrader from an HTML file.

So far I'm able to **scrape** all the values I need, but one.
I've searched and can't find a solution

I need to extract the province "BC" from `data-payment-province="BC"`
from the below code

```
<div class="asLowAs payment-tag-disclaimer" data-payment-tag-adid="66736200" data-payment-province="BC" data-payment-tag-isnew="False" style="display: none" data-toggle="popover">
```

I've used `location = soup.find_all('div', class_='data-payment-province')`

but it returns `[]`

Idk, I'm probably being dumb and missing something obvious but I'm honestly so stumped.

Also, I should probably ask this in another question. But does anyone know how to only get
the values as output instead of the HTML and Values?

e.x.

Current:

```
itemOffered = soup.find_all("span", itemprop="itemOffered")
```

OUTPUT:

```
</span>, <span itemprop=""itemOffered"">
2019 Hyundai Elantra GT | Bluetooth | Backup Camera | Heated Seats | Blind
```

Desired OUTPUT:

```
2019 Hyundai Elantra GT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot for your first problem:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

.....

province_re = re.compile(r'[A-Z]{2}')

location = soup.find_all('div', {'data-payment-province': province_re})

for loc in location:
    print(loc.attrs['data-payment-province'])
```

Comment: That worked! I don't understand why just yet, but I'm going to study it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner approach would be this:

```
divs= soup.find_all('div')

for div in divs:
   if div.has_attrs('data-payment-province'):
      print(div['data-payment-province'])
```

And to get the text of elements you can use this:

```
elements = soup.find_all(['span','element1','element2'])

for element in elements:
   fulltextofelement = element.find(text=True, recursive=True)
   onlyparenttext = element.find(text=True, recursive=False)
```